# Maven Integration installation error?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am new for Hibernate i am trying to Install  Maven Integration but i am getting some error I tried a lot but I didn't get solution. How to solve please any one help me will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Adavance

Attached screenshots please check. 
[image: Image one,]

[image: Imagetwo]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install Maven, it would be better to download the latest maven version from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and configure MAVEN_HOME and restart eclipse

Configuration :   Go to Computer -> Right click -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> Choose  System Variables -> Select New

Add Variable name as MAVEN_HOME and Variable value as < your location of maven>
eg : E:\apache-maven-3.3.9 then under "Path" variable add E:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin.

Done !!! Now restart eclipse and verify

Comment: i download please tell me How i need to configure can you explain?

Comment: Hope you were able to do it